# How to add Player to Maze

Tags: java, swing, maze

I have constructed a maze and made a player class. When I compile it, I only see the maze and not the player. I have tried different techniques and still it doesn't work for me.

What exactly do I have to do in order to see the player and be able to move it?

Also, is there a way to adjust the maze and make it bigger or same size as frame?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  // Needed for ActionListener
import javax.swing.event.*;  // Needed for ActionListener
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class www extends JFrame
{
    static Maze maze = new Maze ();
    static Timer t;

    //======================================================== constructor
    public www ()
    {
        // 1... Create/initialize components
        // 2... Create content pane, set layout
        JPanel content = new JPanel ();        // Create a content pane
        content.setLayout (new BorderLayout ()); // Use BorderLayout for panel
        JPanel north = new JPanel ();
        north.setLayout (new FlowLayout ()); // Use FlowLayout for input area

        DrawArea board = new DrawArea (500, 500);

        // 3... Add the components to the input area.

        content.add (north, "North"); // Input area
        content.add (board, "South"); // Output area

        // 4... Set this window's attributes.
        setContentPane (content);
        pack ();
        setTitle ("MAZE");
        setSize (490, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo (null);           // Center window.
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        www window = new www ();
        window.setVisible (true);
        player p = new player ();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame ();
        //jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
        //jf.setSize(600,400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    class DrawArea extends JPanel
    {
        public DrawArea (int width, int height)
        {
            this.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (width, height)); // size
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            maze.show (g); // display current state of colony
        }
    }
}

class Maze 
{
    private int grid [][];

    public Maze ()
    {
        int [][] maze = 
            { {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};

        grid = maze;

    }

    public void show (Graphics g)
    {
        for (int row = 0 ; row < grid.length ; row++)
            for (int col = 0 ; col < grid [0].length ; col++)
            {
                if (grid [row] [col] == 1) // life
                    g.setColor (Color.black);
                else
                    g.setColor (Color.white);
                g.fillRect (col * 30 + 30, row * 30 + 30, 30, 30); // draw life form
            }
    }
    public class player extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener
    {
        Timer tm = new Timer(5,this);
        private int x = 0; 
        private  int y = 0;
        private int velX = 0 ;
        private int velY = 0;
        public void player ()
        {
            tm.start();
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(20,30,50,50);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            x = x+velX;
            y = y +velY;
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int c =  e.getKeyCode();
            if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                velX = -1;
                velY = 0;
            }
            if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                velX = 0;
                velY = -1;
            }
            if( c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                velX = 1;
                velY = 0;
            }
            if(c==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            {
                velX = 0;
                velY = 1;
            }
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}


    }


}
```

Comment: Issues that I see: 1) You create a JFrame, jf, put nothing in it, yet display it -- why? 2) You create a player object, p, and add it to nothing, and so it will never display. 3) Your player class extends JPanel -- why? I'm guessing that you want to show your player within the maze which is drawn by another JPanel, and by making it extend JPanel, you prevent them from working together with ease.

Comment: My guess is that you created this in your IDE from scratch without first organizing your thoughts on paper, and if so, consider changing this plan. Instead organize your ideas and your program on paper first, and only after doing this should you try to commit code to your IDE.

Comment: Myself, I'd change Player so that it does not extend JPanel, so that it is a *logical* class and not a *component* class. I'd then put it somewhere in my program and then have my drawing JPanel, here called DrawArea, draw the Player object similar to how it draws the Maze object.

Comment: so should be a method instead of a class?

Comment: `"so should be a method instead of a class?"` -- ? I don't recall making that statement -- and am not sure how you get that interpretation from my posts above. And no, that's not true at all. It should be a class that **doesn't extend JPanel**, and you should create an instance of it and add it to your program.

Comment: ^--- What he said. Your problem is, you create an instance of Player but never add it to anything and you're breaking the paint chain requirements by not calling super.paintComponent in your Board class